# phpmyadmin stored procedure error

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run SP in phpmyadmin web-hosting server but always getting following error

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4

**SP I am trying to run is:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Authenticate_UserByEmailID(strUsername VARCHAR(45), strPassword VARCHAR(45))
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM users 
    WHERE users.Username = strUsername AND users.Password = strPassword;
END $$
```

I tried putting single quotes in SP name, table name columns name and different other combinations with quotes but no result then I came across [**this link**](http://blog.nth-design.com/2009/02/25/creating-sp-in-phpmyadmin/) and tried changing delimiter but no result. can you please help on this.

## **Solution:**

Sorry guys my bad. I added delimiter which solved the problem for me.

```
DELIMITER ;;

CREATE PROCEDURE `Authenticate_UserByEmailID`(strUsername VARCHAR(45), strPassword VARCHAR(45))
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM DBCompany_samsonusac517644.users 
    WHERE Username = strUsername AND Password = strPassword;
END ;;
```

Comment: I have been struggling with my SP for an hour, before I came across this one. To use a delimiter. Never heard of it in the SqlServer world. Don't understand it either. but it works!

Answer (score 5):

you miss the `DELIMITER`

```
mysql> delimiter $$
mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE Authenticate_UserByEmailID(strUsername VARCHAR(45), strPassword VARCHAR(45))
    -> BEGIN
    ->     SELECT * FROM users 
    ->     WHERE users.Username = strUsername AND users.Password = strPassword;
    -> END $$
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: @Sandy You can also omit the delimiter, since there's just one statement in the SP. Just remove the `$$` after `END`.

Comment: I already solved the issue by adding delimiter. I appreciate for your help.

Answer (score 0):

All the answers above are making certain assumptions. There are basic problems in 1and1 and certain other hosting providers are using phpMyAdmin versions which are very old and have an issue that defined delimiter is ; and there is no way to change it from phpMyAdmin. Some of the providers have moved on so they will not face this problem. but if you do then following are the ways -

1. Create a new PHPMyAdmin on the hosting provider. Attached link gives you idea http://internetbandaid.com/2009/04/05/install-phpmyadmin-on-1and1/
2. Go thru the complicated route of be able to access the your hosting providers mySQL from your dekstop. It is complicated but the best if you are a serious developer. here is a link to do it http://franklinstrube.com/blog/remote-mysql-administration-for-1and1/

Hope this helps